# SFINAE: Using template child of a template struct

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

What is the proper way of doing such things?

I would like to use conditions on parametrs pack like:

```
static_assert(all_of<ChildTypes ...>::are_in<ParentTypes ...>::value);
```

In short I have code like that:

```
template <class ... Types> struct is_in
{
    template <class Arg>
    struct test : any_of<Types ...>::is_same_as<Arg> {}; // error C2059
};

template <class ... Args>
struct all_of
{
    template <class ... Types>
    struct are_in : all_fulfill<typename is_in<Types ...>::test, Args ...> {};

    template <class Type>
    struct are : all_fulfill<typename is_same_as<Type>::test, Args ...> {};
};
```

where `any_of<Types...>::is_same_as<Type>::value` and `all_of<Types...>::are<Type>::value` work well when being used in functions so `all_fulfill` and `any_fulfills' also work well (always are true_type or false_type).

When trying to call are_in I have following errors:

```
error C2059: syntax error: '<'
error C2039: 'value': is not a member of 'is_in<bool,int>::test<Head>' with [ Head=int ]
error C2065: 'value': undeclared identifier
error C2975: '_Test': invalid template argument for 'std::conditional', expected compile-time constant expression
```

As background:

```
template < template <class> typename Test, typename... List >
struct all_fulfill : std::false_type {};

template < template <class> typename Test, typename Head, typename... List >
struct all_fulfill<Test, Head, List ...>
    : std::conditional< Test<Head>::value, // error C2065 // error C2975
    all_fulfill<Test, List...>, // error C2039
    std::false_type
    >::type {};

template < template <class> typename Test >
struct all_fulfill<Test> : std::true_type {};
```

Tried:

In `struct is_in` adding alias for parent type like:
`using AnyOfTypes = any_of<Types ...>;` and `struct AnyOfTypes : any_of<Types ...> {}`

Expected result:

`all_of<ChildTypes ...>::are_in<ParentTypes ...>::value` should return proper bool.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. `any_of` is `std::any_of` ? When you are using using declaration you should show them

Comment: `std::any_of` is an algorithm not a type trait, inheriting from `std::any_of` makes no sense. Maybe thats already half the answer, but it is unclear becaue `any_of` could be anything

Comment: Another part of the puzzle is probably the fact that `test` is not a `typename`, but a `template`, so that should probably be `is_in<Types ...>::template test`. There's too much work here to turn the isolated code snippets into a single, cogent, [mre], to be able to try this out myself.

Comment: ```template <class Arg, class ... Types>
struct is_in
{
    static constexpr const bool value = (std::is_same_v<Arg, Types> || ...);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Types>
struct all_of
{
    template <typename Arg>
    constexpr static bool contains = (std::is_same_v<Arg, Types> || ...);

    template <typename... Args>
    constexpr static bool are_in = (all_of<Args...>::template contains<Types> && ...);
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(all_of<bool, int>::are_in<int, double, bool>);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Y1j7dedsh